# Javascript codes for preloader gif remove issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an HTML page w/ a preloader.

However for some reason when I remove a part of my JavaScript code w/c is related to preloader, the coming soon page doesnt work anymore.

Here's my JS codes:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    /* ==============================================
    PRELOADER
    =============================================== */
    var preloaderDelay = 500;
    var preloaderFadeOutTime = 800;

    function hidePreloader() {
        var loadingAnimation = $('#loading-animation');
        var preloader = $('#preloader');

        loadingAnimation.fadeOut();
        preloader.delay(preloaderDelay).fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime, function() {
            $('#logo').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
            $('.intro').addClass('animated flipInX');
            $('.timerContent').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            setTimeout ( function () {
                $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="css/animate.css"]').remove();
            },2000);
         });   
    }

    hidePreloader();

    function startPage() {

    } /*  End animation section home  */

});
```

And here's the HTML part where it handles that:

```
<div id="preloader">
    <div id="loading-animation"></div>
</div> <!-- End Preloader -->
```

What should I remove on my JavaScript code to remove this preloader w/o having any issues and so that I can remove the preloader completely but not the animatoion of the logo etc.

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work, what is your cooming soon page, you must ask concise questions :)

Comment: I am trying to remove the preloader from my JS. That's really it. How can I remove the preloader code so that I can stop my preloader.

Comment: You mean you don't need it ?

Comment: yes. exactly. When I remvoe the HTML my whole codes did not work anymore so I am guessing I need to deal with the preloader JS code first

Comment: you mean your animations didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok from comments I think I understood what you need:

JS :

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('#logo').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
    $('.intro').addClass('animated flipInX');
    $('.timerContent').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    setTimeout ( function () {
         $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="css/animate.css"]').remove();
    },2000);


    function startPage() {

    } /*  End animation section home  */

});
```